# c++ - data binding (DataRow and DataModel)

Tags: c++, data-binding

I'm writing a c++ application which reads a delimited text file as input and do some processes on it. obviously to ease things , I've actually created a structure (which represents my data-model).

Well, my difficulty started when another type of input file has been fed in to my application, the simple solution was to hard-code all again (specially the parts related to data-binding and data-conversation) .. but for sake of clean code I decided to follow a standard rule which as far as I know it is all about separating DataRow, DataModel and DataBinding from each other.

Right now, DataRow has dynamic nature, and by that I actually mean, It could read the column of file and expose a simple array of strings, In other hand DataModel is just same as before, I created several Structures to describe the Data structure . However I stuck in designing DataBind class .. I was thinking that DataBind class's objects should have at least below methods:
1- setDataRowColCount ( count )
2- setColProp ( colNo, DataModel.memVar )
3- FillDataObject ( ref to DataModel object )

Can you please share your experience with me, and is there any reliable library for implementing this ?

Thanks,

EDIT:
Development environment: FreeBSD 9.2 Clang++ 3.5 , C++11

Comment: Do you need to get two-way binding?(That is the change in your model should be written to the file.) I am also curious whether your application have any UI and whether the user should be able to redefine binding without app recompilation.

Comment: Thanks for reply, There is no UI interaction, the application is sort of daemon, which receives files from different sources with different file formats.

Comment: I know it's my bad that I have asked multiple questions at once, I will try once again. Do you need also to alter those files or you just need elegant way to read a file? Do you need to add new bindings without recompilation?

Comment: It's ok, it seems I failed to explain my question :) well, those file are not going to be altered by my application, I just need to process those and lets say print out some statistics from them. as I mentioned, Reading files, including separating the data-columns is done. Now, I successfully generate array of strings for each col of data-row. However Binding the array of strings to a DataModel (struct) + type-conversion is my main question.